# PDO Update not updating data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know an answer like this has been written countless amounts of time but honestly after spending about 4 hours on this, I can't seem to find whats wrong. My PDO Update is not updating. It was working a few days ago and maybe I have changed something but it doesn't work at all now.

```
 try {
     $query_update = $db->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE ghl_users SET user_last_reset_code = :user_password_reset_hash,
                                                           user_last_reset_request = :user_password_reset_timestamp
                                                           WHERE user_name = :user_name');
     $query_update->bindValue(':user_password_reset_hash', $user_password_reset_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $query_update->bindValue(':user_password_reset_timestamp', $temporary_timestamp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $query_update->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $query_update->execute();
}catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
   throw new MyDatabaseException( $Exception->getMessage( ) , (int)$Exception->getCode( ) );
}
```

all variables are set (e.g. when I echo it shows me the values)

```
 echo $user_name. "<br />";
 echo $temporary_timestamp. "<br />";
 echo $user_password_reset_hash. "<br />";
```

Values are:

```
johndoe
2015-06-04 09:28:29
8ctkas9f3ef35jdk2k5jaeffe115j3kkdc2ae
```

Comment: try with `$query_update->bindValue(':user_password_reset_timestamp',date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($temporary_timestamp)) , PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: and what is the data type of field `user_password_reset_timestamp`???

Comment: its timestamp.  
If you need my schema to check it out I can send it. I will try your above code now. 
edit: Didnt work :(..
I honestly tried to update just one string field in my database and even that didnt work.

Comment: if it will timestamp then use `$query_update->bindValue(':user_password_reset_timestamp', strtotime($temporary_timestamp) , PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: that didn't work either.. 
Before I tried to update user_email where user_name = :username.. and even that didn't work... I know I am connect to the db because its not throwing an error.. and all these queries don't throw errors either

Answer (score 1):

You only need to parameterise unsafe values , `$user_password_reset_hash`, to stop injection. You can use SQL `NOW()` to update

Try

```
 try {
 $query_update = $db->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE ghl_users 
                                    SET user_last_reset_code = :user_password_reset_hash,
                                                       user_last_reset_request = NOW()
                                                       WHERE user_name = :user_name');
 $query_update->bindValue(':user_password_reset_hash', $user_password_reset_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $query_update->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 if ($query_update->execute())
      {
      // success
       echo "Updated record";
     }
    else
    {
      // failure

   }



}catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
   throw new MyDatabaseException( $Exception->getMessage( ) ,  (int)$Exception->getCode( ) );
}
```

Also 
Ensure `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is set

Comment: huh, can't believe I didn't notice it. Thanks but it still doesn't work. Even if I try to update one field, lets say, user_job where user_name = :user_name

Comment: No error unfortunately. Nothing is returned - just a white page and it stops at the query. I tried echo before and after and the echo before the query works.

Comment: @BhavikP. I have added extra error checking to answer